# Why can't I find chat button link on server faults like its in Stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

Well title explains it all, just made a server fault account and wanted to chat with people about servers but can't find link to chat rooms.

Comment: For the future, Server Fault is for asking questions about systems you manage (per the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq)) -- questions about Server Fault itself belong on http://meta.serverfault.com - I've moved this one for you :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Server Fault!

You may be… disappointed by the often non-server-related topics on [ServerFault chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com). ;)

You'll also need rep on the main site before you can talk in chat. Please ask a good question or answer an existing (unanswered) question to gain rep!

Comment: Why an unanswered question? Even a decent answer to an already answered question can earn rep.

Answer (score 4):

Server Fault chat is a very nice place to hang out.

It is not a good place to talk about questions or ask for help with problems - That's why we have the main site.

Bearing that in mind, you will find Server Fault's chat room in the same place as all the other sites' chat rooms: http://chat.stackexchange.com.